# React Native SDK Directory doesn't exist

Tags: react-native

I am trying to start with React Native. I have created a sample project, but when I try to run it I get the following error

> The SDK directory '/home/praveen/Workspace/ReactNative/AwesomeProject/android/'/home/praveen/Android/Sdk/'' does not exist.

Although the path for the Android SDK is correct :

praveen@CLLAP-CHN-0156:~/Android/Sdk$ ls

add-ons      extras    platforms       skins          temp
build-tools  licenses  platform-tools  sources        tools
emulator     patcher   SDK Readme.txt  system-images

Answer (score 1):

create a file local.properties on [reactproject]/android and add

> sdk.dir = /home/[USER]/Android/Sdk

to file local.properties

Answer (score 0):

You may need to Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable based on the location of the Android SDK. Additionally, consider adding ANDROID_HOME/tools, and ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to your PATH.

[setting up android dev tools](https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/)

Answer (score 0):

(terminal):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

EDIT: should be added as android home path. Full document: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but it's not clear why. If you can add an explanation, it will help other readers as well